# How to access cell property dynamically in uicollectionview in swift

Tags: swift, ios8, uicollectionview, uitextview

Help of UICollectionView I am using textview to display content. Collectionview contain 10 cells. I couldn't specify height of textview according to that textview's content size. I am displaying one cell at a time. In story board, textview height is 240px. But I need content view to be extend according to the content size. My code is below. But if I run,
Error receiving as : FATAL ERROR WHILE UNWRAPPING reading_access having nil value. Kindly guide me!!

```
// MAIN CLASS

class read_page: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate 
{



 @IBOutlet var reading_collection_view: UICollectionView!

 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()


 }



func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: 
 Int) -> Int {

    return 10  
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath:     
NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

  var cell = story_collection_view.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("story_read", 
  forIndexPath: indexPath) as story_reading_cell

          cell.reading_area_txtvw.frame.size.height = 750

  return cell
}

// This code is working. But, from 3rd cell onwards it is working. When we compile,  
// textview does not change. After scrolling two more cells, it is working. How to get 
// its size from first cell onwards? How to change cell size?




}
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to register the collectionViewCell then in the cellForItemAtIndexPath you can dequeue the cell.

I would also not use a UIViewController, I would instead use a UICollectionViewController as this provides the defaults delegate and datasource implementations.

```
class read_page: UICollectionViewController {

    @IBOutlet var reading_collection_view: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        reading_collection_view.registerClass(reading_cell.self , forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "myCell")
    }

//MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let myCell = reading_collection_view.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as reading_cell
        myCell.reading_area_txtvw.frame.size.height = myCell.reading_area_txtvw.contentSize.height
        return myCell

    }
}
```

Comment: THREAD 1: EXC_BAD INSRUCTION(CODE = EXC_1386)   Error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value